# How to setup ANTLR grammar for a C constant structure?

Tags: c, antlr

I'm trying to use ANTLR4 in a C# console application to parse out a version number out of an auto-generated C file (compiled with IAR). For some reason it doesn't seem to like my constant declaration.

**The ANTLR error I'm getting is 'mismatched input '=' expecting {'(', '*', '^', ':', ';', Identifier}**

```
//Declared in another file...
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t major;
    uint16_t minor;
    uint16_t build;
    uint16_t revision;
} 
VERSION;

//In the C file I'm trying to parse
const VERSION version =
{
    .major = 1,
    .minor = 2,
    .build = 3000,
    .revision = 40000,
};
```

This is the C# code I am working with to try and parse this. I'm pretty sure StructDeclaration is wrong but I'm still not getting any tokens after initializing the Lexer.

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
     AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(stream);
     CLexer cLexer = new CLexer(inputStream);
     CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(cLexer);
     CParser cParser = new CParser(commonTokenStream);

     CParser.StructDeclarationContext decl = cParser.structDeclaration();
}
```

This is the g4 file that I am using.
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4

What rule(s) do I need to add to be able to support this?

Comment: I don't get any errors when I feed the code from your question to the grammar you've linked. Are you sure the code you've posted is exactly the same as the one you're getting that error message for?

Comment: Yes, the only other code is 1 #include and a comment header

Comment: If you take the exact code in your question, copy it into a file and then try to parse that file, do you get the error? If not, the one include or the comment are clearly relevant.

Comment: If I use this exact code my error is extraneous input 'typedef' expecting {'__extension__', '__m128', '__m128d', '__m128i', '__typeof__', 'char', 'const', 'double', 'enum', 'float', 'int', 'long', 'restrict', 'short', 'signed', 'struct', 'union', 'unsigned', 'void', 'volatile', '_Atomic', '_Bool', '_Complex', '_Static_assert', Identifier}

Comment: And you're sure that you're using the exact same grammar that you linked? You didn't edit it? How are you running the parser? From your C# code? If so, please post that code. Which rule are you invoking? Maybe something other than `compilationUnit`?

Comment: 100%, I think I may have an idea of what is wrong. What context would this fall under? I was using StructDeclaration but I think that is wrong...

Comment: Edited with C# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CParser.StructDeclarationContext decl = cParser.structDeclaration();
> ```

The `structDeclaration` rule would be able to parse the `struct ... VERSION;` part, but it can't handle the `typedef` keyword before it nor the variable definition that comes after it because those aren't part of struct declaration.

When parsing an entire file, `compilationUnit` is the rule you want to invoke (in fact, it's really the only one that's meant to be invoked from the outside - that's why it ends with `EOF`).

Comment: Fixed. Thank you for your time and assistance.